# Freeform Install Error

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm trying to install Freeform and after install I click Freeform from the modules list and I get the error below...

> Fatal error: Class 'Freeform_mcp' not found in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/sysadmin/expressionengine/controllers/cp/addons_modules.php on line 344

I'm using Expression Engine Version v2.8.1.

I've uninstalled and tried again but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Freeform are you trying to install?

Comment: Freeform 4.2.2.

Comment: I notice it's looking is a sub-directory of the httpdocs folder, you've set up your base path in the EE configs correctly right? Basically I'm wondering if the path in your error message is right, is the file and class there?

Comment: Did you solve this?I am getting the same error after trying to update to Freeform version 4.2.5